What is special about Bravais lattices when understood as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules
In solid state physics, an essential concept is that of Bravais lattices. An $n$-dimensional Bravais lattice $\mathcal{L}$ can be defined as the integer combinations of $n$ primitive lattice vectors $\{a_i\}$:
$$\mathcal{L} := \{\vec{R} \in \mathbb{Z}^n:\vec{R} = \sum_i z_i a_i\}.$$
In particular, a Bravais lattice is just a special $\mathbb{Z}$-module. I am wondering what insight can be gained from thinking of a Bravais lattice in terms of being a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Since, as you say, a lattice is a special case of a module, why would thinking about the less specific structure provide more insight?

For the same reason that understanding the abstract properties of differential equations gives one general and helpful statements (e.g. existence and uniqueness theorems) about solving the Maxwell equations, etc. @Ghoster
